# How can I lower the water intake on my booster pump from the main water pump?

Tags: pipe, water-pressure, valve, well-pump

I have a 25 foot shallow well for water sprinkler with 2 horse power barracuda pump. Low pressure so added 3/4 hp barracuda booster pump. Booster is dry running for lack of water from main pump. How can I lower the booster intake too stop dry run?

Comment: where is the air getting in?

Comment: What do you consider low water pressure, I have had both simple suction and jet pumps on wells that could easily pump 80 psi. Is the primary pump or the line(s) to the water the real problem?

Comment: My main pump has 1 1/4 inch in and out of pump. I don’t believe their is no air leak. Took everything apart and resealed piping. My sprinkler system has was too many misters and rotating heads on each zone. My cut on and off pressure is 40/20 with pressure take attached. Put muriatic acid in piping to well and let set for a day before hooking back up.  With booster off. The main pump builds pressure and shuts off in less than minute so I have water. I sank well my self 24 years ago. Please help. Getting fed up.

Answer (score 0):

@Ed Beal is right in his comments so you should not need a booster pump. I think it is time to check out the primary pump and piping to and from the pump since a 2 HP pump will move a lot of water at a very high pressure. A booster pump should not be necessary.